# How to effectively communicate a message was sent via email in a complaint

Tags: pleadings

Question: Is there prose that is more effective to rebut the Defendant's claim of not receiving a **message**?   IANAL and would like to understand how to effectively communicate to the Authority (judges, etc.) who are not necessarily versed with modern technology (i.e. still using fax).

Context: A Florida defendant is bound to broadcast a **message** per Florida statute.   The plaintiff emailed the **message** and requested confirmation to the plaintiff's agent.  The Defendant's **agent** contemporaneously acknowledged via email receiving the email that contained said message along with other related information.  The Defendant now claims that the agent did not received the message.

Speculation: either the defendant (including it *agent*) has failed to read the email containing the **message** sufficiently or the defendant response is pretextual

A complaint must be in written form and is limited to "the four corners" of the written complaint.   Given that the message was sent via email with a specific date and time stamp.  What is the most persuasive written strategy to claim and **demonstrate** that said **message** was sent and received?    Given the prose:

> Plaintiff emailed the **message** to the defendant and requested for
> confirmation of receipt in said email.   Defendant's *agent* replied
> via email on 1/1/70 15:30PM to the plaintiff's inquiry.  The
> **message** was provided in a two-page attachment and are provided in the complaint's exhibit #123.

Is there prose that is more effective to rebut the Defendant's claim of not receiving the message?  I pose the question because IANAL and would like to know if there is any issue with the substance or form, from the perspective of either a practicing attorney or judge.

Comment: Reads effective enough to me.  Is there some point you think might unclear, or has potential to be misinterpreted?  Are you just looking to fluff it up with lawyerspeak like “caused to be emailed, sent, transmitted, caused to be sent…”?

Comment: @MichaelHall. Thank you for the feedback.   I am seeking to keep it as simple / concise as possible.

Comment: I'd say your wording is adequate then.  And I don't think your question has an answer, because you seem to be seeking editorial opinions.  For that reason this may get voted closed

Comment: Is there any significance to bolding most (but not all) occurrences of the word "message"?  Is the context different between the bold and un-bold examples?